# where is getCount function() magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, layered-navigation

In `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/mana/filters/items/list.phtml`file
there is a line 
`$_item->getCount()`
I am looking for `getCount()` function as my website's layered navigation filter is not working properly, and found it in few files. These are the files

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Decimal.php
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Price.php
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Compare/Item.php
/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogIndex/Model/Attribute.php
/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogIndex/Model/Price.php
/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogIndex/Model/Resource/Attribute.php
/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogIndex/Model/Resource/Price.php
/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Block/Product/Abstract.php
/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Block/Product/Viewed.php
/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Product/Index/Abstract.php
/app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Block/Customer/View.php
/app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Block/Product/List.php
/app/code/local/AW/Advancedreports/Model/Additional/Reports.php
```

I renamed `getCount()` method in all these files and still this line 
`$_item->getCount()` is working fine. It is still showing count for filters. Anyone could help me locate this function and if this function is in above files then why it is still working after I have renamed the function.

It is related to magento core functionality, and I have looked in `/app/code/local` folder also for this function, if anyone had override the function, but could not find it.

Comment: What's your goal? You want to hide number or something else?

Comment: count is showing wrong for some attribute filters, I am debugging the cause. So for that I am looking for  getCount()  function

Comment: @keyurshah can you tell me which function is responsible for showing counts beside filters in layered navigation

Comment: It is hard to say because I am unfamiliar with the `mana` extension that you are using.  It is possible that `count` is an attribute of your `$_item`, and if so, the code would be the same as `$_item->getData('count')`.  That being said, you should be able to find your function by going to `/app` and run the CLI command `grep -rn 'code' -e 'function getCount()'`.  That will return any matching strings in any of the three code folders..

Comment: @mtr.web you are right, count was actually an attribute of $_item.

Comment: Happy to help :)